# MaterialDrawerTheme.ActionBar - not correct show states of android.support.v7.preference.SwitchPreferenceCompat

Tags: android

Android Studio 4

```
 defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 28
```

In my xml

```
<android.support.v7.preference.SwitchPreferenceCompat
            android:defaultValue="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_fingerprint"
            android:key="fingerprint"
            android:layout="@layout/preference_layout"
            android:persistent="true"
```

If I set this theme:

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="MaterialDrawerTheme.ActionBar">

<item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
<item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
<item name="colorAccent">#3a9a20</item>
<item name="android:textColor">@color/primary_text</item>
<item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/secondary_text</item>
<item name="preferenceTheme">@style/PreferenceTheme</item>
<item name="android:windowContentTransitions" tools:targetApi="lollipop">true</item>
<item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/AppAnimationStyle</item>
<item name="android:windowBackground">@color/background</item>
<item name="actionModeStyle">@style/ActionMode</item>
<item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
<item name="actionModeCloseDrawable">@drawable/ic_close</item>
```

and here result:

[image]

As you can see the turn on is correct show, but turn off is **NOT CORRECT SHOW**

Now I change theme to this:

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">#3a9a20</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/primary_text</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/secondary_text</item>
    <item name="preferenceTheme">@style/PreferenceTheme</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentTransitions" tools:targetApi="lollipop">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/AppAnimationStyle</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/background</item>
    <item name="actionModeStyle">@style/ActionMode</item>
    <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="actionModeCloseDrawable">@drawable/ic_close</item>
```

and now here result:

[image]

and now both states (on/off) SHOW CORRECT.

The question is:
Why theme **MaterialDrawerTheme.ActionBar** not correct show states of component "**android.support.v7.preference.SwitchPreferenceCompat**" ?

Comment: The two themes don't even define the same attributes... possibly it relies on `android:textColorSecondary`? Also, is there any reason why you're not using AndroidX?

Comment: @Nicolas It's wold project and use appcompat library in whole project.